docker-compose: Getting fe_sendauth: no password supplied in pgadmin:8.12
I have been trying to create a passwordless set-up for pgadmin with a postgres DB instance via docker-compose.
services:
  db:
    hostname: dbserv
    container_name: dbserv
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - dbnet
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
      
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:${PGADMIN_VERSION-8.12}
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_EMAIL-admin@admin.com}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_PASSWORD-root}
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - dbnet
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
      - ./servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json # preconfigured servers/connections
      - ./pgpass:/tmp/pgpass # passwords for the connections in this file
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy    
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      mkdir -p /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/$${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL_STORAGE};
      cp /tmp/pgpass /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/$${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL_STORAGE}/pgpass;
      chmod 660 /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/$${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL_STORAGE}/pgpass;
      chown pgadmin:root /tmp/pgpass;
      chown pgadmin:root /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/$${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL_STORAGE}/pgpass;
      /entrypoint.sh
      "
networks:
  dbnet:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db-data:
  pgadmin-data:

The servers.json is below:
{
    "Servers": {
        "1": {
            "Name": "TestDB",
            "Group": "TestServers",
            "Host": "dbserv",
            "Port": 5432,
            "MaintenanceDB": "root",
            "Username": "root",
            "ConnectionParameters": {
                "sslmode": "prefer",
                "passfile": "./pgpass"
            }
        }
    }
}

And here is the pgpass:
dbserv:5432:root:root:root
dbserv:5432:postgres:root:root

I still keep getting the fe_sendauth: no password supplied error message when I try to connect with the TestDB within the TestServer.

Here is the first bit of the log from the pgadmin container.
chown: /tmp/pgpass: Operation not permitted
email config is {'CHECK_EMAIL_DELIVERABILITY': False, 'ALLOW_SPECIAL_EMAIL_DOMAINS': []}
NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.
pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
======================================
----------
Loading servers with:
User: admin@admin.com
SQLite pgAdmin config: /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db
----------
Added 1 Server Group(s) and 1 Server(s).
postfix/postlog: starting the Postfix mail system
[2024-10-27 19:38:33 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 22.0.0
[2024-10-27 19:38:33 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
[2024-10-27 19:38:33 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2024-10-27 19:38:33 +0000] [126] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 126
::ffff:172.18.0.1 - - [27/Oct/2024:19:40:26 +0000] "GET /browser/ HTTP/1.1" 302 229 "http://localhost:5050/login?next=/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
...
::ffff:172.18.0.1 - - [27/Oct/2024:19:41:41 +0000] "GET /browser/server_group/nodes/ HTTP/1.1" 200 428 "http://localhost:5050/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-10-27 19:41:41,987: ERROR  pgadmin:    Could not connect to server(#1) - 'TestDB'.
Error: connection failed: connection to server at "172.18.0.2", port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
::ffff:172.18.0.1 - - [27/Oct/2024:19:41:41 +0000] "POST /browser/server/connect/2/1 HTTP/1.1" 401 289 "http://localhost:5050/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
...

Trying to connect with psql with or without setting the PGPASSWORD works either way for both DBs:
docker exec -it dbserv psql -U root -d postgres
docker exec -it dbserv psql -U root -d root
PGPASSWORD=root docker exec -it dbserv psql -U root -d root
PGPASSWORD=root docker exec -it dbserv psql -U root -d postgres

I have scoured the web, but haven't found any solution that works for me.
